# How Do You Concat URL in Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

I need to create a URL that pulls a Mongo ID, but I'm not sure how to concatenate it.  I think I need a helper, but the docs weren't really clear.  I'm trying to make something like this:

```
<a href='/updateReminder/'+photo._id>Update Details</a>
```

because photo._id isn't a string, I'm not sure how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than I thought.

```
<a href='/updateReminder/{{this._id}}'>Update Details</a>
```